# Modify data using trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have the following requirements in SQL server.
I want to get updated/inserted values, edit it save to one column using SQL trigger.

Say I have column named customer_name, when someone updates/inserts value to that column, I want to get that data(the data which is going to be updated/inserted), edit it and save it in different/same column.

I want to rename the values with just to maintain uniqueness in the data. I will append _number if the duplicate data is inserted/updated.

I have column 'name', whenever new duplicate names updated/inserted to the column I want rename it with name_count so that I can maintain uniqueness

I cant go for other solutions since it will take a lot of time. For a time being I have planned to do this.

How can I do it using SQL trigger?

Comment: Edit manually what is going to be inserted/updated? Or just apply some script to change the value? Please clarify what  do you mean, edit.

Comment: @Serg Edited the question.

Comment: Although I can thing about some ways to open GUI interface from trigger code and wait for a user reaction, I should say it's a way to a total disaster. Can you be more specific, why you need it?

Comment: @Serg Given my actual requirement in the question. Can you please help me to achieve it?

Comment: Never did it myself, and most probably never will. I can thing about creating SQL CLR function which can do something like that directly, or if Sql Server blocks any GUI assembly then may be through  com interface of some special exe. May be someone else can help better, sorry.